# Unzip File: Permission Denied

Tags: zip, unzip

I am trying to unzip a file (Facebook download-your-info zip file), but here's what I got:
[image]

Is there a way I can force-unzip it?

Update: I tried `sudo unzip file.zip -d destination_folder` in terminal, and it unzipped the file, but what came out, all the files have size 0 bytes:
[image]

Update 2: I do have permission to the directory and the file.

[image]

(I'm really sorry if my question is asked badly. Let me know down in the comments :) )

Comment: Did the unzip command return an error?  You can check the integrity of the archive by using the command: « unzip -t archive.zip »   It seems that the downloaded archive is corrupted or incomplete.  Is it possible to download it again?

Comment: I downloaded it 2 times on my computer, one time on another computer (and another facebook account data), and all didn't work

Comment: Did the integrity check return something ?

Comment: I checked it and 'No errors detected in compressed data of <name>.zip.' came out

Comment: In fact, I can read every file inside

Comment: @Guillaume Are there any more ways?

Comment: I am not sure to understand when you said « I can read every file inside ». Are you able to compare the size of the archive and the folder using « du -sh /path/uncompressed_folder » ?

Comment: I don't understand the "compare the size of the archive and the folder" part. What folder?

Comment: In your download directory type « ls -la » and note the Facebook archive size. Next, go to your /home/.../temp_file and type «  du -sh <facebook_uncompressed_archive> ».

Comment: when i use the `du -sh` command all of it shows `du: cannot access 'temp_file/pages/no-data.txt': Permission denied
`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Either you try to unzip your archive in a directory where you do not have access rights or the rights on the archive are not granted to you. You can easily check using `ls -la` command and change permissions using `chown` and `chmod` commands.

You can also try unzipping from the command line as a super user and choose a directory where you have access rights.

```
sudo unzip file.zip -d destination_folder
```

Answer (score 1):

Following solution works for me:
cd into file parent's dir then execute unzip cmd.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Before answering an old question having an accepted answer (look for green ✓) ensure your answer adds something new or is otherwise helpful in relation to them. Here is a guide on [answer]. There is also [tour] for the site tour, and [help] for the help center.