# Download-Your-Info Unzip failed

Tags: linux, unzip

I am trying to unzip a Facebook download-your-info zip file, but here's what I got:
[image]

Is there a way I can force-unzip it?

I tried `sudo unzip file.zip -d destination_folder` in terminal (I use Linux), and it unzipped the file, but what came out, all the files have size 0 bytes:
[image]

I do have permission to the directory and the file.
[image]

(I'm really sorry if my question is asked badly. Let me know down in the comments :) )

Comment: This is really unrelated to the fact that the zip comes from Facebook, so I removed the tag.

Comment: Looks like destination permission problems, maybe just `mkdir out; cd out; unzip file.zip;` might work. Just in case, tried checking the archive, with for example `zip --test`?

Comment: @Xen2050 I tried everything

Comment: I already asked the exact same question here: https://superuser.com/q/1387336/959959